# HTML editor with HTML beautifier

Tags: windows, open-source, html, html-editor, code-beautification

On Windows, I'd like to be able to edit some HTML that's been stripped of whitespace. So I would like some sort of HTML beautifier feature, syntax highlighting and tab indenting would be nice.

Not after any drag and drop / WYSIWYG features as I'd be handcoding. The lighter/smaller the better. Oh, and free/open source.

Comment: If you're using Firefox: There's an addon (HTML Validator) which has a "cleanup" function including re-formatting/beautifying. You could export the results to continue in a different editor then. Just saying in case there are only options without the "cleanup/reformat" included, so you could combine.

Comment: Although not free or open source or small, but Visual studio (and I maybe WebMatrix which is small and free) can auto-format and usually does it on paste. The free version of VS should be able to do this.

Comment: As a quick alternative (which I use), on linux, you can install tidy from the repos, then just `tidy -im filename` which will prettify with indents and modify the original `filename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SynWrite**](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/), free and open-source. It has HTML beautify, call menu item <kbd>HTML</kbd> → <kbd>HTML Tidy</kbd> → <kbd>Tidy - reformat only</kbd>.

Other HTML items in Tidy menu - for different tasks, more choices of reformatting.
JS/CSS beautify also exists: just see Python plugins site.

[image: Synwrite interface: HTML menu]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eclipse + [Eclipse Tidy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsetidy/) ([Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/html-tidy-eclipse-plug)):

- free and open source
- cross-platform
- HTML beautifier feature:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) has a plugin called HTMLBeautify which you can install through the [Sublime Package Manager](http://sublime.wbond.net/). It is a beautiful editor, but just an editor and no more.